# How to change the String argument of method, to a unknown class type

Tags: java

I have an interface to return a String value in a method callback. How can I change the return String value in the method, to allow Integer, Double, Custom Objets. Etc.

```
public interface ReturnHandler {
    void onResult(String value);
}
```

Comment: [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Elaborating on what Jack suggested (edit: before deleting their comment), you can either make the interface generic and make your method parameter the generic type of the interface, or use a generic method instead. If the parameter is within a short, known set of types, you can also simply overload the method.

Answer (score 3):

Use generics, like this:

```
interface ReturnHandler<T> {
    void onResult(T value);
}
```

..and implement it like this:

```
class X implements ReturnHandler<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void onResult(Integer value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or anonymously:

```
ReturnHandler<String> handler = new ReturnHandler<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(String value) {
       ...      
    }   
}
```

And alternative is to use generics only on the method:

```
interface ReturnHandler {
    <T> void onResult(T value);
}
```

implemented like this:

```
class Y implements ReturnHandler {

    @Override
    public <T> void onResult(T value) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

then you can call `onResult` with any type:

```
Y y = new Y();
y.onResult("String");
y.onResult(23);
y.onResult(new Object());
```

Comment: "And alternative is to use generics only on the method:" This is effectively the same as just declaring the parameter type `Object`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes true, this option might be of better use when using more than one type parameter for params and return value I guess.